# Auto-Incrementing Sequence Field: Counters Collection vs Optimistic Loop

Tags: mongodb, auto-increment

I need to implement an auto-incrementing field and found this nice article in the docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/
Please note there is no alternative to a real auto-incrementing field in my case (such as timestamp solution).

I was wondering which way I should go now, [Counters Collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/#auto-increment-counters-collection) or [Optimistic Loop](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/#auto-increment-optimistic-loop). What are the advantages and disadvantages of either solution. What should be considered in terms of performance and scaling. I will use the  auto-incrementing field in a read- and write-heavy collection.

In addition I am worried about the following:

> Generally in MongoDB, one does not use an auto-increment pattern for
>   _id's (or other fields), as this does not scale up well on large database clusters. Instead one typically uses Object IDs.

What is the actual issue here? I don't need to use the _id field as the auto-incrementing field but my auto-incrementing field will be indexed and the collection will be queried by this field.

Comment: The scaling concern is that auto-incrementing sequences introduce a dependency on a single source of truth to find the "next" sequence number before successfully inserting a document. A more scalable approach would allow IDs to be generated in a distributed fashion (for example, the approach taken for [ObjectIDs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/)). Can you elaborate on your use case for the auto-incrementing field? Perhaps there is an alternative approach that might suit your requirements.

Comment: Makes sense. My use case is the following: I need a datastructure that logs changes of other services and the user needs to query this structure to get all elements that that have been added since the last time he queried (given an ID of the last element of the last query). Since this happens very often and in concurrency I need to ensure real insertion-order (which holds for the optimistic loop but not for the Counters Collection approach as far as I understand). I don't want to use capped collection either because they cannot be sharded.